# Can't deallocate 2D array with free in C

Tags: c, arrays, types, free, dealloc

im trying to dealloc a Matrix i've created in `MatrizCrea(n,m)` using `MatrizLibera(v)`, but both of the `free()` are telling me that there is a conflict of types.

I've done this code following severa sources, so I'm quite unsure of why this error is happening.

```
header.h

typedef struct Matriz {int n, m, **d;} Matriz;

Matriz MatrizCrea(int n, int m);
void MatrizLibera(Matriz v);



body.c

Matriz MatrizCrea(int n, int m) {
    Matriz mat;
    mat.n = n;
    mat.m = m;

    int ** val = (int*)malloc(n*sizeof(int*));
    int i = 0;
    for (; i<n;i++) {
        val[i] = (int*)malloc(m*sizeof(int*));
    }

    mat.d = val;
    return mat;
}

void MatrizLibera(Matriz v) {
    int i = 0;
    for (; i<v.n; i++) {
        int *a = v.d[i];
        free(a);
    }
    free(v);
}
```

How should I be deallocating the 2D array?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `val[i] = (int*)malloc(m*sizeof(int*));` looks wrong.. Suggest `val[i] = malloc(m*sizeof *(val[i]));`  (wrong type)

Comment: are you sure about `free(v)`? Shouldn't it be `free(v.d)`? Also, as an optimization, those functions should return a pointer and take a pointer argument.

Comment: `int ** val = (int**)malloc(n*sizeof(int*));`, `val[i] = (int*)malloc(m*sizeof(int));`, `free(v.d);`

Comment: @chux Thanks for the answer. Unfortunatelly, im still getting the same "Conflicting types for free()" error.

Comment: @user3121023 It does, but I store it in another matrix when calling it, the .n and .m,  get passed to the new matrix directly and the only thing that needs to be a pointer is the .d, i believe. (Id do `matriz name = MatrizCrea(4,5);`)

Comment: [online compiler C99 has no error](http://ideone.com/okXOUB)

Comment: This is *not* a 2D array, but only an emulation of it. C as of C99 has it much simpler, `int (*arr)[n] = malloc(sizeof(int[m][n]));` does it much simpler. Also don't cast the return of `malloc`, this may hide errors.

Comment: It was definitelly my compiler. I reinstalled and everything started compiling well T.T I don't understand. Thanks all.

Comment: passing a instance of the matrix rather than a pointer to the instance has many problems including massive duplication of the data and many unnecessary 'hidden' memory areas that can be used for nothing else and many hidden calls to memcpy().  pass pointers instead of instances of the matrix.

Comment: the code is trying to free() the whole matrix rather than just free the memory pointed to by 'd'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following

```
Matriz MatrizCrea( int n, int m ) 
{
    Matriz mat;

    mat.n = n;
    mat.m = m;

    mat.d = malloc( n * sizeof( int* ) );

    int i = 0;
    for ( ; i < n; i++ ) 
    {
        mat.d[i] = malloc( m * sizeof( int ) );
    }

    return mat;
}

void MatrizLibera( Matriz *mat ) 
{
    if ( mat->d != NULL )
    {
        int i = 0;
        for ( ; i < mat->n; i++ ) 
        {
            free( mat->d[i] );
        }

        free( mat->d );

        mat->d = NULL;
        mat->n = 0;
        mat->m = 0;
    }
}
```

You can also insert a code in function `MatrizCrea` that will check whether the memory was allocated successfully.

Comment: Umm, still the same problem, conflicting type wont allow me to compile. And I hoped not to use a pointer in the declaration of `MatrizLibera`. Thanks

Comment: @Xaring There is no any conflicting type.

Comment: There is in my machine :S Thanks for the help anyways, ill try after I install the compiler again.

Comment: @Xaring do you put `#include <stdlib.h>` ?

Answer (score 0):

In your MatrizCrea you made an error in the second malloc:
this

```
for (; i<n;i++) {
        val[i] = (int*)malloc(m*sizeof(int*));
    }
```

your sizeof should be of an int not an int pointer

EDIT: another error:

```
   int ** val = (int*)malloc(n*sizeof(int*));
```

the types don't match it should be:

```
    int ** val = (int**) malloc(n*sizeof(int*));
```

for the deallocating I would use:

```
for(i = 0; i < v.n ; i++) {
    free(v[i]);
}
free(v);
```

Comment: It should be `v.d[i]` and `v.d` as im storing the array in `v.d` in first place... Still getting the conflicting type error. I guess I will reinstall my compiler :S

Comment: @Xaring I don't think it's your compiler. What you may check: Do you have an `#include <stdlib.h>` in the right place? Do you compile your code as C or as C++? With gcc, make sure that you compile with `gcc`, not with `g++`. Not every code that's valid C is valid C++, and your casts in your `malloc()` invocations hint that you might be compiling your code as C++ code.

Comment: @cmaster It is my compiler, it must be. I used an online compiler and it was fine, and yes,i use GCC not G++.

Answer (score 0):

header.h

```
// dont typedef struct definitions
struct Matriz {int n, m, **d;};

// pass and return pointers
struct Matriz* MatrizCrea(int n, int m);
void MatrizLibera(struct Matriz* v);
```

body.c

```
struct Matriz* MatrizCrea(int n, int m) 
{
    // indent code blocks
    struct Matriz* mat = malloc( sizeof struct Matriz );
    if (NULL == mat )
    {
        perror( "malloc for matrix struct failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, malloc successful

    mat->n = n;
    mat->m = m;

    if( NULL == (mat->d = malloc(n*sizeof(int*)) )
    {
        perror( "malloc for d failed" );
        free(mat);
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, malloc successful

    memset( mat->d, '\0', n*sizeof(int)); 

    int i = 0;
    for (; i<n;i++) 
    {
        if( NULL == (mat->d[i] = malloc(m*sizeof(int)) )
        {
            perror( "malloc for d[x] failed" );
            for(i = 0; i < m; i++ ) { free(mat->d[i]); }
            free( mat->d );
            free( mat );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }

        // implied else, malloc successful
    } // end for
    return mat;
} // end function: MatrizCrea



void MatrizLibera(struct Matriz* v) 
{
    int i = 0;
    for (; i<v->n; i++) 
    {
        free( v->d[i]);
    }
    free( v->d );

    free(v);
} // end function: MatrizLibera
```

Comment: the code will need to include string.h for the malloc() and free().  the code will need to include stdlib.h for exit() and EXIT_FAILURE